# The Network tab of devtools does not load media

Tags: microsoft-edge, devtools

First, I apologize for the bad English, because I'm using a translator, second, I'm totally layman about devtools.
And when I say layman, I mean I don't know the correct names or terms, but I know what I want to do.

So when I open devtools and click on network - Media, nothing comes up.

I want to download a video from a site where idm doesn't work, but when I go to the media option, nothing shows up, so I would like to know what I am doing wrong, or if I am forgetting something.

I will leave the site here, so you can better understand how it works.

https://animeszone.net/video/vinland-saga-2-episodio-11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an investigation, I've found that websites with copy-righted video resources may chop a single resource into multiple pieces, or separate video tracks from audio tracks. In that case, you won't find them under "Media". But you can still find them under "All", and then sort them by size. Usually, media resources have a relatively larger size.